# handle websocket connections on multiple instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I need to understand the concept of handling websockets on multiple instances so that it could be shared across all the instances. For e.g I have three nodes running which is being connected by the load balancer. On receiving the data which needs to be emit on the specific socket. My initial idea was to create a hashmap or json objects to holds the websocket connections. But I realize that this couldn't be done in this way as it will be only specific to its particular instance. If I will receive the data on any of the instances then most of the data will not be going to emit on that websocket connection as it doesn't know on which instance the websocket is created. Is there a good way to handle websocket connections so that it could be shared on all instances. My ideas was to use redis or postgres sql database because they are shared among all the instances.

Also I have tried the postgres solution to store the websocket connection but when I save the connection it says

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Is there some good solution to handle websocket connections that could be shared among all instances. If database is a good solution how can I resolve

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 0):

I guess the thing you are looking for are `Adapters`, and it's being documented relatively well in the official socket.io documentation ([/v4/adapter/](https://socket.io/docs/v4/adapter/)).

> When scaling to multiple Socket.IO servers, you will need to replace the default in-memory adapter by another implementation, so the events are properly routed to all clients.

You have several official adapters you can choose from :

- Redis adapter
- MongoDB adapter
- Postgres adapter
- Cluster adapter

Here is an example using the `MongoDB` Adapter :

```
npm install @socket.io/mongo-adapter mongodb
```

```js
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { createAdapter } = require("@socket.io/mongo-adapter");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// DATABASE CONNECTION
const DB = "mydb";
const COLLECTION = "socket.io-adapter-events";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const io = new Server();

const main = async () => {
  await mongoClient.connect();

  try {
    await mongoClient.db(DB).createCollection(COLLECTION, {
      capped: true,
      size: 1e6
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // collection already exists
  }
  const mongoCollection = mongoClient.db(DB).collection(COLLECTION);

  // HERE COMES THE IMPORTANT PART :)
  // CREATE MONGO DB ADAPTER AND USE IT 
  io.adapter(createAdapter(mongoCollection));
  io.listen(3000);
}

main();
```

The adapter then will take care of the rest. Every packet that is sent to multiple clients (e.g. `io.to("room1").emit()` or `socket.broadcast.emit()`) will be

- sent to all matching clients connected to the current server
- inserted in a MongoDB capped collection, and received by the other Socket.IO servers of the cluster

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I have question can bull queue be a solution? As it is also connected to redis and can bull queue publish the messages to all instances?

Comment: `bull-queue` is for creating a queue , as in task queue (so a process can work through them one by one ... ) . Yes `bull-queue` also utilizes redis, so I guess it would be possible to have a queue spanned across multiple nodes, where redis would keep them in synch. Unfortunately this has nothing to do with socket.io. What is your use-case with socket.io ? I might have missed something.

Comment: Thank you again. Actually I am getting data from one sever as a real time data. I want to process that data and send the data to the user devices. So I was thinking sockets is a good solution as user can signin on multiple devices and have it's own socket connections and then it's data can be synchronised amongst his all devices. For local it is working fine but in our distributed environment it is not working as sometimes realtime data arrive on instance1, sometime instance2 and if socket connection is on instance1 and data arrived on instance2 then it cannot be received.

Comment: Now to overcome this problem I was thinking of some queuing mechanism or what you have suggested in your answer.

Comment: So data sometimes is emitted to instance1 and sometimes to instance2 - this perfectly describes the problem of a multi-node socket.io cluster. By default one socket.io node doesn't know anything about other socket.io nodes and their connections - this is where one of those adapters come into play. When all socket.io connections are synched across all socket.io nodes , then you can keep all those socket connections of 1 user in 1 socket.io room and then just emit to that room. Haven't worked on a multi-node socket.io setup myself, these are just my thoughts at this point.

Comment: yeah so I need to now work on what you have suggested in your answer. I am gonna try this out and will let you know the results :)